# How can I store a numpy array as a new column in PySpark DataFrame?

Tags: numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, numpy-ndarray

I have got a numpy array from `np.select` and I want to store it as a new column in PySpark DataFrame. How can I do that?

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

pdf = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1,2,3], 'b': ['abc', 'cde', 'edf']})
df_data = spark.createDataFrame(pdf, schema='a string, b string')
```

There are a few conditions and choices for which I use `np.select` like

```
np.select(conditions, choices, default='Other')
```

This returns the following nd-array

```
[['val1'], ['val2'], ['val3']]
```

Now I want to save this nd-array as a new column in `df_data`.

Comment: Could you provide som example-code? I.e. the pyspark-code to create your DataFrame and the python-code to create the Numpy-array?

Answer (score 2):

You may try first converting your ndarray to list and providing every element of the list to its appropriate location into Spark array.

```py
ndarray = np.select(conditions, choices, default='Other')
nd_list = ndarray.tolist()
df_data = df_data.withColumn('ndarray', F.array([F.array(F.lit(e[0])) for e in nd_list]))
```

This way you would create array of arrays which would probably be an equivalent of your list of lists.